# Solution of systems of equations: $ \vec{x}''(t) =A\vec{x}(t)$ is similar to fourier series, is there a connection between these two?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

The solution of the system of linear differential equations of the form

$$ \vec{x}''(t) =A\vec{x}(t)$$

Is given in the form:

$$ \vec{x}(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n \left( a_j \cos(\omega t) + b_j \sin (\omega t) \right) \vec{v} $$

The fourier series is given by:

$$ s_n = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^N \left(a_n \cos\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{P} nx \right) + b_n \sin\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{P} nx \right) \right) $$

This looks very similar. Is there a simple connection between these two?

Comment: If $A=-W^2$ you get $x=\exp(iWt)c+\exp(-iWt)d=\cos(Wt)a+\sin(Wt)b$ with matrix functions, $a=x(0)$, $Wb=x'(0)$. Using an eigen-decomposition of $A$ or $W$ you get something like your first version.